# Python: How to make variables consistent throughout different functions?

Tags: python, variables, input, scope

I'm still starting out how to program in Python, and I'm just wondering how to make a variable consistent throughout different functions. For example, a function that I've made modified a variable. Then, I've used that variable again in another function. How can I make the modified variable appear in the 2nd function? When I try it, the 2nd function uses the original value of the variable. How can you make it use the modified value? Do I need to use global variables for this?

Also, is the input() function recommended to be used inside functions? are there any side effects of using it inside them?

Comment: With the input(), you just have to check what the user enters (never trust him!). Don't let him to enter values that could make your programm crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[global](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)** variabale to access variable throughout code.

Demo:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> def test():
...   global a
...   a = a + 2
... 
>>> print a
10
>>> test()
>>> print a
12
>>>
```

---

In class, use class variable which is access to all instance of that class. OR use instance variable which is access to Only respective instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The variables need to be shared by a scope that is common to both functions, but this need not necessarily be a global scope. You could, for instance, put them in a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
    def inc(self):
        self.x += 1
    def dec(self):
        self.x -= 1

mc = MyClass()
print mc.x # 10
mc.inc()
print mc.x # 11
mc.dec()
print mc.x # 10
```

What scope exactly the variable should exist in depends on what you're trying to do, which isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` in the function.

```
x = 3

def change1():
    x = 5
    return x

x = change1()

def change2():
    print(x)

change1()
change2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global keyword at the top of the function to let python know that you are trying to modify the variable in global score. Alternatively, you could use OOP and classes to maintain an instance variable throughout class functions.

```
x = 5

def modify():
    global x
    x = 3

modify()
```